How to collapse / expand an area of a Flutter MultiSplitView with a custom divider?
I'm trying to build a resizable multi-area web page with Flutter using package MultiSplitView. Resizing by drag and drop works as expected, but I could not figure out how to fully collapse an area. Also the IconButton in the middle of the divider is not visible, although it works (as can be seen on the fixed vertical divider).
Example code main.dart:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:multi_split_view/multi_split_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        title: 'MultiSplitView',
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        home: const MyHomePage(),
      );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isClosed = false;
  double width = 200;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('MultiSplitView collapsible dividers')),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            _buildHorizontalDivider(),
            Divider(),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  _buildVerticalDivider(),
                  VerticalDivider(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: MultiSplitView(
                        dividerBuilder: (Axis axis,
                                int index,
                                bool resizable,
                                bool dragging,
                                bool highlighted,
                                MultiSplitViewThemeData themeData) =>
                            _buildVerticalDivider(),
                        initialAreas: [
                          Area(builder: (context, area) => Draft.blue()),
                          Area(builder: (context, area) => Draft.yellow()),
                          Area(builder: (context, area) => Draft.green())
                        ]),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildHorizontalDivider() => Row(
        children: [
          const Expanded(child: Divider(color: Colors.red)),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_up),
            onPressed: () => debugPrint('button up pressed'),
          ),
          const Expanded(child: Divider(color: Colors.red)),
        ],
      );

  Widget _buildVerticalDivider() => Column(
        children: [
          const Expanded(child: VerticalDivider(color: Colors.blue)),
          IconButton(
            icon:
                Icon(isClosed ? Icons.arrow_right : Icons.arrow_left_outlined),
            onPressed: () => setState(() => isClosed = !isClosed),
          ),
          const Expanded(child: VerticalDivider(color: Colors.blue)),
        ],
      );
}

File pubspec.yaml:
name: untitled
description: "dividers alignment test"
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.4.4 <4.0.0'
dependencies:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  multi_split_view: ^3.2.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

